# Adjust horizontal scrolling speed on a mouse or trackpad independent of the vertical speed

Tags: mouse, macos

I have recently bought a Logitech M510 as my main mouse switching over from a magic mouse. I didn't realize missing horizontal scrolling would be such an issue, but apparently it is.

Now a mac does support horizontal scrolling by holding shift + scrolling, this is however amazingly slow.

I have the Logitech Control Center installed, which offers a few extra options, but nothing regarding the horizontal scroll speed. The scrolling speed options offered there only affect vertical scrolling.

[image: settings screenshot]

Can the vertical speed be one setting and the horizontal speed another?

Answer (score 3):

You can make the horizontal scroll speed faster and independent by overriding the native <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>scroll</kbd> function with [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/)'s feature to define a custom relationship between inputs, scroll speed, and direction. You can even assign a scroll speed acceleration value if you want to combine slower and faster scroll speeds for enhanced precision.

Here's how to set it up:

1. In the SteerMouse preference pane, select the "Mouse" tab.
2. Switch the "Horizontal scrolling" option from "Tilt" to "Roll" (Fig. 1). This should be enough to let SteerMouse take over the handling of horizontal scrolling, which is what is invoked when you use the native <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>scroll</kbd> function, so if you don't wish to make further scroll speed adjustment, you can stop here.
3. Select the "Scroll" tab (Fig. 2).
4. Click the "Roll Horizontally" button.
5. Make any further acceleration and sensitivity adjustments. You can also invert the horizontal scroll direction (Fig. 3).

[image: Fig. 1]
[image: Fig. 2]
[image: Fig. 3]

Answer (score 3):

I think Logitech has updated their mouse scroll settings since this answer was asked, and now their settings allow you to adjust horizontal scroll speed. Yay!

I recently (April 2020) bought a Logitech M705 mouse, and once you plug its little usb receiver into your computer for the first time you've got the option to install the "Logi Options" app, which contains a bunch of adjustable settings for your Logitech devices.

1. Open the Logi Options app
2. Select your mouse
3. You'll see horizontal scroll speed options.

[image: Logi Options screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

have you tried increasing the speed in Accessibility options? 
[image]

Comment: Not a bad idea. Since I haven't used the mouse in question (or anything similar) for over two years, I can't really say if this would solve it. Thanks nonetheless for the answer!

Comment: Just saw that you asked this two years ago. I was just browsing unanswered questions. I hope your Logitech journey has been better than mine.