# MacBook pro 16" - Big Sur - find config file to change the speed of horizontal scrolling speed

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, big-sur, text-editor, macos

On my MacBook pro 16", I would like to find out where is the parameter that controls the speed of horizontal scrolling with trackpad (if it is possible).

Indeed, I am using some different editors and I would like to increase the speed of horizontal scrolling, so I wonder if it can be performed by changing parameter(s) in one or different configuration file(s).

In system preferences, there is not such an option that enables to do it (only vertical scrolling speed).

Any information about this is welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136237/adjust-horizontal-scrolling-speed-on-a-mouse-or-trackpad-independent-of-the-vert?rq=1

Comment: @X_841 . Thanks for your quick answer. Keeping shift + horizontal movement on trackpad increases significantly the horizontal scrolling. Is there a way to remap this combination (shift + horizontal movement on trackpad) just by a simple horizonatl movement on trackpad ? I am going to do some research about it . Regards